# NoReverseMatch at reset_password_complete: Django PasswordResetConfirmView

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am using Django's default password reset views and forms to send an email to the user for them to reset their password via a link in the email. I have most of the development complete but am stuck on one issue. When I receive the email from the local host, I click the link, enter my new password 2 times, hit 'submit' and get this error: [Error Message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSJIn.png)

Below is my code.
urls.py

```
"""defines URL patterns for users"""

from django.urls import path, include, reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    # include all default auth urls
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path(
        'reset_password/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/password_reset.html',
            success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')
            ) ,
            name='reset_password'
    ),
    path(
        'reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
            success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_complete')
            ),
            name='password_reset_confirm'
    ),
    path(
        'password_reset_done/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
            template_name="registration/password_reset_sent.html"),
            name='password_reset_done'
    ),
    path(
        'password_reset_complete/',
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
            template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html'),
            name='password_reset_complete'
    ),
    path('forgot_username/', views.forgot_username, name="forgot_username"),
    path('username_retrieval/', views.username_retrieval, name="username_retrieval"),
]
```

As you can see, I am using the namespace 'users' in the success_url variable, however, it seems to work on the `reset_password` path, but it does not seem to work on the `reset/<uidb64>/<token>` path.

One thing to be aware of is that I have a custom user model in my application. Would that affect my ability to use this default Django password reset method?

In addition, here are my templates under the users/templates/registration/ folder: [User App Templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUrMS.png)

Some other things to mention:
When I click on the link from my email, I am directed to `password_reset_confirm` and not `password_reset_form` so that tells me that the template name is not being overwritten as well.

When I change
`success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_complete')`
to
`success_url=reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_completed')`
the app doesn't look for `users:password_reset_completed` so that implies that the `success_url` is not being overwritten.

Any help would be appreciated and I can post more code and answer questions if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line is overwriting all your paths:

```
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

just remove it or if you want to keep some of them place it at the end after your paths

Comment: It worked. Thank you so so so much! Out of all of the research I did, I didn't find that as a plausible solution and it makes total sense now.